# Is there a way to disable "Show notifications" check for specific application programmatically?

Tags: android, notifications, admin

Is there a way to disable "Show notifications" check for specific application programmatically?

This check is here:
Settings->APps->Click on any app from a list-> Show notifications

I need to do a program that disables or enables this check for showing user notifications for specific application. In fact it doesn't meter for me, which method I use, I just need to disable or enable notifications for specific application (or for all applications).
My app has device administrator permission, so, it will not be a problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no
if it was an option every developer would re-enable him self the option to show notifications

you could send the user to the app page on settings and let him check or un check the option